# FinalBuilder: Add Build Number, Current Date, Time and Subversion revision to output executable version info

Tags: delphi, finalbuilder

I want to set output executable InternalName something like that:

```
ProgramName_build_300_rev_100_201303141324.exe
```

where:

- `300` - build number
- `100` - latest subversion revision
- `201303141324` - date/tame of build

Comment: Are you using TortoiseSVN by any chance?

Comment: I don't use FinalBuilder, but in the tool I use I found it easier to run a batch copy of the original file to the new filename.  And the values you are looking for are probably stored as internal variables in the build script.  Thus: run "copy original.exe copy_%build%_%rev%.exe" after the successful compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no problem at all in FinalBuilder. But you have to collect these information first, store it in variables and copy/rename the resulting file.

- You can get the revision number (last changed revision) with the svn info action
- There is an action for date/time info, with which you can get your timestamp

As a last step, rename the file, using the variables in the name, e.g. ProgamName_build_%build%*rev*%rev%_%timestamp%.exe